# Is there a fast way to check if a variable belongs to a set?

Tags: php, set, element

I have a form and I need to check if a input belongs to enum(0,1,2,3,..,n)
Is there a simple way to check if my variable belongs to the set [0:n] ? Or do I have to write each condition (basically n<10, so it's feasible but not that practicle...)?

If there ain't native function to do that, could you give me a hint on how to make a function for this?

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you specifying your set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Example:

```
$number = 5;
$set = range(0, 10);
if (in_array($number, $set))
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about range(), really practical one.

Answer (score 1):

```
$set = range(0,n);
if (in_array ($value, $set)) {
    print "IS IN ARRAY!";
}
```

This is true for range from 0 to n
If you want to make specific range. f.e. 0,1,3,7, you can use

```
$set = array(0,1,3,7...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the [range](http://php.net/range) and run [in_array](http://php.net/in_array), but that probably wouldn't be great for performance. PHP would internally end up looping through the numbers you provided to create a brand new (potentially huge) array, and then loop through the array all over again to see if X is in there somewhere. That's a lot more work than necessary for a simple "is it within these numbers" check.

Sticking to the two conditions is probably the best way to go, especially since it'd be much more readable. You can also make a helper function if this is, for some reason, really getting to you.

```
function is_within_inclusive($x, $start, $end) {
    return $x >= $start && $x <= $end;
}
```

But if you already have the range defined, anyway, for other reasons, [in_array](http://php.net/in_array) seems fine.